# Disabling the a specific payment method for variable-product with specific attribute value in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a WordPress website:
I want to disable one of the payment methods (`snapppay`) for variable products with `3ml`, `5ml`, or `10ml` values for attribute `vol` if only these products are in the cart.
For example, my customer should be allowed any number of products with `3ml`, `5ml`, or `10ml` values WITH AT LEAST one product with any different `vol` (not 3, 5 or 10ml)
I tried this code but my website stops working:

```
function modify_available_payment_gateways($gateways) {
$flag = false;
$cart = WC()->cart;
$cart_num = count($cart->get_cart());
$dec_num = 0;
// Loop through cart items
foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    if( $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ){
            // Loop through product attributes values set for the variation
            foreach( $cart_item['variation'] as $term_slug ){
                // comparing attribute term value with current attribute value
                if ($term_slug === '3ml' || $term_slug === '5ml' || $term_slug === '10ml') {
                    $dec_num = $dec_num + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    if ($cart_num === $dec_num){
        $flag = true;
    }
}

// When the flag is true
if ( $flag) {
    // Clear all other notices          
    wc_clear_notices();

    // Avoid checkout displaying an error notice
    wc_add_notice( __( 'My Error Message.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    
    // Optional: remove the payment method you want to hide
    unset($gateways['snapppay']);
}
return $gateways;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'modify_available_payment_gateways');
```

Comment: Look at this example and update to your needs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67070379/prevent-woocommerce-checkout-if-cart-only-contains-sold-individually-items

Comment: @Snuffy thank you, and I think it is different from my question
do you see what's the problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this issue, you need first to target checkout only and also your code can be simplified.

Try the following:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'modify_available_payment_gateways');
function modify_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() && isset($available_gateways['snapppay']) ) {

        // Loop through cart items
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if( $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ){
                // Loop through product attributes values set for the variation
                foreach( $cart_item['variation'] as $term_slug ){
                    // comparing attribute term value with current attribute value
                    if ( ! in_array($term_slug, ['3ml', '5ml', '10ml']) ) {
                        return $available_gateways;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return $available_gateways;
            }
        }

        unset($available_gateways['snapppay']);
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.